# Google Calendar in Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am using the [0.5.5 version of the gcal4ruby gem](http://cookingandcoding.com/gcal4ruby/) on my rails 3.0 app and I am 
seemingly having trouble creating an event.  I can start service, and 
create a calendar just fine, but I get the following error when I try 
to create an event:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `debug' for #<GCal4Ruby::Calendar: 
0x1036d8a68> 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:242:in `to_xml' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:236:in `map' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:236:in `to_xml' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:230:in `create' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gdata4ruby-0.1.5/lib/ 
gdata4ruby/gdata_object.rb:155:in `save' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:225:in `save' 
        from (irb):92
```

I looked at the code in this line, and it seems like it is checking 
whether or not the service.debug = true, not the calendar, so i'm not 
sure why it is throwing this error.  Here's how I got here in IRB, 
line by line:

```
service = GCal4Ruby::Service.new 
service.authenticate(MY_GOOGLE_LOGIN, MY_GOOGLE_PASS) 
calendar = GCal4Ruby::Calendar.find(service, 'Test 2', :first) 
event = GCal4Ruby::Event.new(calendar) 
event.title = "test title" 
event.content = "test content" 
event.where = "my house" 
event.start = Time.now 
event.end = 2.hours.from_now 
event.all_day = false 
event.calendar = calendar[0] 
event.save 
NoMethodError: undefined method `debug' for #<GCal4Ruby::Calendar: 
0x1036d9990> 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:242:in `to_xml' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:236:in `map' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:236:in `to_xml' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:230:in `create' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gdata4ruby-0.1.5/lib/ 
gdata4ruby/gdata_object.rb:155:in `save' 
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gcal4ruby-0.5.5/lib/gcal4ruby/ 
event.rb:225:in `save'
```

I must be missing something here, but I'm not sure what.  Obviously I 
am getting a valid calendar object...is there some attribute that I am 
missing?

Alternatively, if anyone has any other suggestions as to what to use for a calendar solution I would love to hear it. Basically I need to allow users to add predefined events to a calendar, which can be recurring, and ideally I'd like for them to be able to export these calendars for use in outlook, ical, etc... Is there a way to do this via web?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is annoying, i seem to have it working. it was a matter of changing:

```
event = GCal4Ruby::Event.new(calendar)
```

to

```
event = GCal4Ruby::Event.new(service)
```

even though that's directly contrary to what i had read in the documentation.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm having the same problem but changing from calendar to service does nothing for me.