# Rails 3 Application With Exportable Calendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar, fullcalendar

I am looking for a way to implement calendar functionality into my rails 3 app.  I was originally planning on using GCal4Ruby but [I can't get it to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827440/google-calendar-in-rails-3-app). I'm not married to google calendars, but I want a way to embed the calendars into a page, and create recurring events.  If possible I would like to be able to export these calendars for use in outlook, ical etc, but I'm not entirely sure this is possible.  It seems like my two options are: gcal4ruby or fullcalendar using jquery.  Are there any other solutions.

If you could point me in a good direction I would certainly appreciate it!

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar